# Why is the following protobuf-net usage illegal?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

```
  public interface IYObject
  {
    string X { get; }
  }

  public class YObject : IYObject
  {
    public string X { get; set; }
  }

  public class D
  {
    public IYObject Y { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var m = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
      m.Add(typeof(D), true).Add("Y");
      m.Add(typeof(IYObject), false).AddSubType(1, typeof(YObject)).Add("X");
      var d = new D { Y = new YObject { X = "a" } };
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, d);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var d2 = Serializer.Deserialize<D>(ms);
        Debug.Assert(d.Y.X == d2.Y.X);
      }
    }
  }
```

The code fails when I try to add a subtype to `IYObject`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=Sub-types can only be adedd to non-sealed classes
  Source=protobuf-net
  StackTrace:
       at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.AddSubType(Int32 fieldNumber, Type derivedType)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: "Sub-types can only be adedd to non-sealed classes" - it isn't a class, so it certainly isn't a non-sealed class. I will be looking to raise this restriction, in line with your (and existing) request(s). But first.... sleep.

Comment: You really are giving me a work-out ;p I applaud it - you are forcing me to add a lot of polish on areas that people have been requesting since v1. The ***entire point*** of the new v2 type-model was to make this kind of flexibility (from your however-many posts) possible, and so far I'm pretty pleased that the versatility needed is there in the new model (i.e. nothing has been much of a show-stopper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before about 2 minutes ago, it was illegal because known-types weren't supported against interfaces.

*Now*, that usage is illegal because it can't safely serialize `IYObject.X` because it *has no setter*. However, as long as we restrict ourselves to interfaces members that can be sensible serialized, or members on the concrete type, this is now committed. Using either attributes or the type model. [See here for the scenarios that are now available](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/Issues/SO6115986.cs) (via either code, or the next public drop).

Comment: What is the meaning of the boolean argument in RuntimeTypeModel.Add method?

Comment: @Mark `<param name="applyDefaultBehaviour">Whether to apply the inbuilt patterns, or jut add the type with no additional configuration.</param>` - or in short (and I'll clarify the documentation) - if it is false, no attributes are processed - you must configure the type fully manually